# Python TypeError: 'module' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm, web-crawler

I am trying to write a web crawl using python with pycharm IDE. I have written a basic code for crawling three elements of a website by using 'items'. Now I am facing the error "TypeError: 'module' object does not support item assignment".

---

```
import scrapy
from .. import items
from ..items import QuotesItem
class QuotesSpider (scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'https://quotes.toscrape.com/'
    ]
    def _parse(self, response):
        div_tags = response.css('div.quote')
        for x in div_tags :
            title = x.css('span.text::text').extract()
            author = x.css('.author::text').extract()
            tags = x.css('.tag::text').extract()
            items['title_item'] = title
            items['author_item'] = author
            items['tag_item'] = tags
    
            yield items*****
```

Comment: What is `items` is that a module (to `import QuotesItem`) or a `dict`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this function, you have the variable assignment the other way around. It should be like this

```py
    def _parse(self, response):
        div_tags = response.css('div.quote')
        for x in div_tags :
            title = x.css('span.text::text').extract()
            author = x.css('.author::text').extract()
            tags = x.css('.tag::text').extract()
            title = items['title_item']
            author = items['author_item']
            tags = items['tag_item']
    
            yield items*****
```

Comment: I'd expect this to now give "TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable" (if `items` is a module).